# Hex inside python

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex, type-conversion

So this is the program im writing for bruteforcing simple xor encryption, but I cant seem to get my finalHex to stay in base 16, as when I add, I want it to roll over.  I tried many things like (int(finalHex,16)) but i get an error like:
can't convert non-string with explicit base.  Is there anyway to convert it, or to keep it base 16 through the entire program? ('B' is going to be supplied via sys.argv in the future)

```
def bruteforce():  
    s=int('B',16)  
    startingHex = s  
    for i in range (1,250):  
        print("About to XOR",i,"with",startingHex)  
        finalHex = startingHex ^ s  
        for a in range(1,250):  
            print("About to add",a,"with",finalHex)  
            finalHex = a + finalHex  
            if finalHex == 0:  
                print("Decoded!")  
        continue  
def main():  
    bruteforce()  

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    main()
```

Comment: `finalHex` is not a hexadecimal string. It is an integer *already*. Are you asking how to format that integer as a hexadecimal string again?

Comment: In which case, `hex(finalHex)`

Comment: @jonrsharpe: or `print("About to add {:02x} with {:02x}".format(a, finalHex))` perhaps.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - That worked, but the number there is a DWORD and it has to only be 16 bits, is there a way to just keep everything base 16 for the entire process?  I.e if I add 0x2 to 0xFF instead of becoming 0x101 it would be 0x1.

Comment: Mask the number with biwise AND then; `finalHex & 0xff` removes all but the last byte. Note that that's *8* bits, not 16. 16 bits is 0 to FFFF

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Sorry ya, 8 bits.  So, what do you mean mask the number with biwise and then the finalhex & 0xff, could you give me an example?  Id really appreciate it.  Also, would it work in the case and say like you were at 0xF3 after xoring and then added 0x62 to it?

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators : `'{:02x} {:02x} {:02x}'.format(0x100 & 0xff, 0x64a & 0xff, 0x398fe & 0xff)` -> `'00 4a fe'`.  so `& 0xff` keeps the last 8 bits and sets the higher bits to zero.